# Put data from user in matrix with loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, input

I'm new in matlab, I've searched a lot but I didn't find my answer. I want to get data from user in a for loop and put that data in matrix. I used this code:

```
npattern=inputdlg('Enter the number of Patterns');
a=npattern(1,1);
for i=1 : a(1,1);
    r=inputdlg('Enter Data');
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work for me. What should I do now?

Comment: What doesn`t work exactly? What do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `r` can contain strings (not just numbers):

```
npattern=inputdlg('Enter the number of Patterns');
a=str2num(npattern{1});
for ii=1:a;
    r{ii}=inputdlg('Enter Data');
end
```

Comments:

- `inputdlg` returns a cell array of strings
- it's bet not to use `i` as a variable (`i` is `sqrt(-1)` by default)
- `r` in your code is overwritten at each iteration. Better use a cell array
- there is one `end` too many

Answer (score 1):

```
x=inputdlg('Enter the number of Patterns');
data = str2num(x{:}); 
r = zeros(data, 1);
for i=1:data
    x = inputdlg('Enter Data');
    r(i, 1) = str2num(x{:});
end
```

Comment: Not sure it can be assumed that the second `inputdlg` should accept a single number (at each iteration).

Comment: Partial question, partial answer :)